# Changing the text of a UITextField does not trigger the rx.text binder

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a `UITextField` called **commentField** and I create an `Observable<Bool>` like this:

```
let isCommentFieldValid = self.commentField.rx.text.orEmpty.map({ !$0.isEmpty })
```

This observable determines whether a button is enabled or not.
The problem is that when I change the text property of `commentField` liked this:

```
self.commentField.text = ""
```

The **isCommentFieldValid** doesn't trigger again and, thus, the button's state doesn't change. Any edition using the UI works: if I remove all text from the field through the keyboard, the **isCommentFieldValid** updates, but via code it doesn't.

Is there a reason this doesn't work?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you look at the underlying implementation for `rx.text` you'll see that it relies on the following `UIControlEvents`: `.allEditingEvents` and `.valueChanged`. Explicitly setting the `text` property on `UITextField` does not send actions for these events, so your observable is not updated. You could try sending an action explicitly:

```
self.commentField.text = ""
self.commentField.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For me, it only worked when I used `.allEditingEvents`.